# Rendering a ServiceStack Razor view programmatically

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to render a ServiceStack Razor page programmatically on the server (so I can send it via email).  I am following the info on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/RqMnfM73ic0 post, but when I call the "AddPage" method with a valid path for the cshtml file, it falls over.

```
var response = svc.Get(oReq);

        var razor = TryResolve<RazorFormat>();
        var path = @"C:\GetOrderResponse.cshtml";
        var razorPage = razor.AddPage(path);
```

This throws an Argument Exception with the message:

Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.
Parameter name: path2

```
 at System.IO.Path.InternalCombine(String path1, String path2)
 at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.GetFullSearchString(String fullPath, String        searchPattern)
  at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetDirectories(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.EnumerateDirectories(String dirName)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory.GetDirectoryFromBackingDirectoryOrDefault(String dName)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.GetFile(Stack`1 virtualPath)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualDirectoryBase.GetFile(String virtualPath)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.AbstractVirtualPathProviderBase.GetFile(String virtualPath)
at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.MultiVirtualPathProvider.GetFile(String virtualPath)
at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager.GetVirutalFile(String ospath)
at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager.AddPage(String filePath)
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.AddPage(String filePath)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this from within a ServiceStack service? and does this page already exist under **/Views/**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely don't want to add the page which should already be added if it's under `/Views/`. Instead you can resolve the existing page by name and render it to html with:

```
var razor = HostContext.GetPlugin<RazorFormat>();
var orderPage = razor.GetViewPage("GetOrderResponse");
email.BodyHtml = razor.RenderToHtml(orderPage, order);
```

Comment: Has this broken as of v4.0.15?  Has been working fine, upgraded over weekend, and the GetPageByName is now not finding any Views.

Comment: @Gumzle Still works for me. Are you getting any StartUp errors in `?debug=requestinfo`. See debug info about [RequestInfo plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info).

Comment: great tip - urg - 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.  Will dig. Thanks again

Comment: this method has disappeared from 4.0.16 - do I need to do something else?

Comment: @Gumzle Yeah it's either `GetViewPage(pageName)` or `GetContentPage(pathInfo)` depending if it's a ViewPage within `/Views` or ContentPage served outside it.

Comment: The view is in the /Views folder (which is also copied to output folder), and GetViewPage("viewnamehere") always returns null.  Checking the RazorViewManager that is returned from CreateViewManager(), the Pages collection is empty.  The ScanRootPath is the correct bin location.

Comment: @Gumzle is this is self-hosting you need to set the BuildAction to `Copy if Newer` so it can find it in the bin/ directory

Comment: no, is in iis8, and all views are set the build action to 'Copy Always' - have tried 'copy newer' too after your post, but nothing.

Comment: @Gumzle look for Startup Errors in `?debug=requestinfo` needs to be in [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode)